# Finding where a parametric curve crosses itself

Tags: calculus

Could someone explain to me why, when finding where a parametric curve crosses itself, there are two distinct t values to be found instead of one?

My initial thinking was that there would be a distinct point x(t) and y(t) where the curve intersects itself and this would happen at a time t. Why is this wrong?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can think the curve as a track, if it crosses itself it means that you pass through the point before at time $t_1$ then once again at time $t_2$ and so on

Comment: Good...your welcome ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Because, when a parametric curve (parametrized by "time" in your metaphor) there is a first time the curve arrives at the crossing point and the second time the curve arrives at the crossing point.  Consider this glyph
$$  \alpha  $$
If we parametrize this curve, by labelling points along it in increasing time order, we will find there are two time labels at the crossing point -- one placed the first time we arrived there and one placed the second time we arrived there.